# TYPO3 Fluid: f:uri.action encodes & with &amp;

Tags: typo3, fluid, typo3-8.x, viewhelper

I'm currently updating a TYPO3 6.2 website to TYPO3 8.7 and have a problem with html encoded ampersands.

This is the code:

```
<f:uri.action action="xml" extensionName="foobar" pluginName="barbazxml" controller="Items" pageType="102" arguments="{exclude:exclude,cat:cat}" />
```

In the old website, this renders this URL:

```
rdf.xml?tx_foo_bar%5Bexclude%5D=123&tx_foo_bar%5Bcat%5D=117&tx_foo_bar%5Baction%5D=xml&tx_foo_bar%5Bcontroller%5D=Items&cHash=4310d7e9385e74b2eee5380aa0d46e1f
```

As you can see, the ampersands are ok.

In TYPO3 8.7 I get this URL:

```
rdf.xml?tx_foo_bar%5Bexclude%5D=123&amp;tx_foo_bar%5Bcat%5D=117&amp;tx_foo_bar%5Baction%5D=xml&amp;tx_foo_bar%5Bcontroller%5D=Items&amp;cHash=4310d7e9385e74b2eee5380aa0d46e1f
```

The ampersands are converted to `&amp;`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe `{f:uri.action() -> f:format.raw()}` would help?

Comment: If you prefer tag syntax, this should work too:

`<f:format.raw><f:uri.action /></f:format.raw>`

Answer (score 1):

The technical background:

Since TYPO3 v8.0, ViewHelpers escape their HTML output by default ([Breaking: #69863 - Changes in ViewHelpers post Standalone-Fluid](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/core/Changelog/8.0/Breaking-69863-ChangesInViewHelpersPostFluidStandalone.html))